# PHP insert elements before, between and after some array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I've a multidimensional array of some arrays, in which the first values are ordered and included in a specific range.

Example:

```
A1=[[0,a],[3,b],[5,c],[6,a],[9,c]]
```

in which `A1[i][0]` are in `range (0,10)`

How can I obtain an array where, if the first value
 (`A1[i][0]`) isn't a value present in the first array, e.g.

```
A1[i][0]==2
```

I insert an array with that value in the right position, with a specified second value (example A)?

Example of output i want:

```
A1=[[0,a],[1,A],[2,A],[3,b],[4,A],[5,c],[6,a],[7,A],[8,A],[9,c]]
```

Comment: PHP variables begin with `$`.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Loop through the array. If the first element of `$A1[$i]` isn't `$i`, use `array_splice()` to insert the element `[$i, 'A']` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help

```
$A1 = [[0,'a'],[3,'b'],[5,'c'],[6,'a'],[9,'c']];
foreach($A1 as $A2) $A3[] = $A2[0];//make a new array contain keys of the first array.
for($i=0;$i<=9;$i++){
    if(!in_array($i, $A3)){
        $A1[] = [$i, 'A']; //check if the key not exist, make a new array with key who does not exist.
    }
}
asort($A1);//sort the new element inside the array
print_r($A1);
```

output is,

```
[[0,a],[1,A],[2,A],[3,b],[4,A],[5,c],[6,a],[7,A],[8,A],[9,c]]
```